# Turn a string into a list of lines in python

Tags: python

Example:

```
string = """i like to program
i need attention
12345 67890
abcdefghijkl mnopqrstuvwxyz"""
string = function(string)
print(string)
```

> > ["i like to program" ,"i need attention", "12345 67890", "abcdefghijkl mnopqrstuvwxyz"]

Note, i know about the split() function, i just want to know if there is any function that splits only lines and not spaces.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Didn't know about splitlines. It's weird they include it since Python tries to have "only one obvious way to do it" and `split('\n')` is pretty clear for me.

Comment: @PauloBu Try both of them on `'a\r\nb\nc'`.
`

Comment: Yes I know about different line endings and thought about it but still, it pretty easy to handle them with `split` IMHO. In any case good to know :)

Comment: Actually it got a little messy when I tested hehe. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

As *@iCodez* suggests, it's best to use `str.splitlines`.

While, on first sight, this may seem the same as doing `split('\n')`, **they have different behaviours**.

`\n` on python represents a line-break, independently from the platform where you run it. However, [this representation is platform-dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations). On windows, `\n` is two characters, `CR` and `LF` (ASCII decimal codes 13 and 10), while on any modern unix (including OS X), it's the single character `LF`.

`print`, for example, works correctly even if you have a string with line endings that don't match your platform:

```
>>> print "a\x0ab\x0d\x0ac"
a
b
c
```

However, explicitly splitting on "\n", will yield platform-dependent behaviour:

```
>>> "a\x0ab\x0d\x0ac".split("\n")
['a', 'b\r', 'c']
```

For this reason, it's best to use `splitlines`:

```
>>> "a\x0ab\x0d\x0ac".splitlines()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Great answer, IMO you should post this one in dup thread as well. 85K views, comes right at the top in Google search. :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I did that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`string.split('\n')` will suffice. Or explicitly `string.splitlines`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.splitlines`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
>>> string = """i like to program
... i need attention
... 12345 67890
... abcdefghijkl mnopqrstuvwxyz"""
>>> string.splitlines()
['i like to program', 'i need attention', '12345 67890', 'abcdefghijkl mnopqrstuvwxyz']
>>>
```